# Casting pointer & its address to integer pointer

Tags: c

What is the difference between the following two assignments?

```
int main()
{
    int a=10;
    int* p=  &a;

    int* q = (int*)p; <-------------------------
    int* r = (int*)&p; <-------------------------
}
```

I am very much confused about the behavior of the two declarations.
**When should i use one over the other?**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
int* q = (int*)p;
```

Is correct, albeit too verbose. `int* q = p` is sufficient. Both `q` and `p` are `int` pointers.

```
int* r = (int*)&p;
```

Is incorrect (logically, although it might compile), since `&p` is an `int**` but `r` is a `int*`. I can't think of a situation where you'd want this.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int a = 10;   /* a has been initialized with value 10*/

    int * p = &a; /* a address has been given to variable p which is a integer type pointer
                   * which means, p will be pointing to the value on address of a*/

    int * q = p ; /*q is a pointer to an integer, q which is having the value contained by p,                     * q--> p --> &a; these will be *(pointer) to value of a which is 10;

    int * r = (int*) &p;/* this is correct because r keeping address of p, 
                         * which means p value will be pointer by r but if u want
                         * to reference a, its not so correct.
                         * int ** r = &p; 
                         * r-->(&p)--->*(&p)-->**(&p)                             
                         */
       return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int main()
{
    int a=10;
    int* p=  &a;

    int* q  = p; /* q and p both point to a */
    int* r  = (int*)&p; /* this is not correct: */
    int **r = &p; /* this is correct, r points to p, p points to a */

    *r = 0; /* now r still points to p, but p points to NULL, a is still 10 */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Types matter.

The expression `p` has type `int *` (pointer to `int`), so the expression `&p` has type `int **` (pointer to pointer to `int`).  These are different, *incompatible* types; you cannot assign a value of type `int **` to a variable of type `int *` without an explicit cast.

The *proper* thing to do would be to write

```
int  *q = p;
int **r = &p;
```

You should never use an explicit cast in an assignment unless you know *why* you need to convert the value to a different type.